# Creating and plotting confidence intervals

Tags: r, glm, confidence-interval

I have fitted a gaussian GLM model to my data, i now wish to create 95% CIs and fit them to my data. Im having a couple of issues with this when plotting as i cant get them to capture my data, they just seem to plot the same line as the model without captuing the data points. Also Im also unsure that I've created my CIs the correct way here for the mean. I entered my data and code below if anyone knows how to fix this

data used

```
aids
 cases quarter  date
1      2       1 83.00
2      6       2 83.25
3     10       3 83.50
4      8       4 83.75
5     12       1 84.00
6      9       2 84.25
7     28       3 84.50
8     28       4 84.75
9     36       1 85.00
10    32       2 85.25
11    46       3 85.50
12    47       4 85.75
13    50       1 86.00
14    61       2 86.25
15    99       3 86.50
16    95       4 86.75
17   150       1 87.00
18   143       2 87.25
19   197       3 87.50
20   159       4 87.75
21   204       1 88.00
22   168       2 88.25
23   196       3 88.50
24   194       4 88.75
25   210       1 89.00
26   180       2 89.25
27   277       3 89.50
28   181       4 89.75
29   327       1 90.00
30   276       2 90.25
31   365       3 90.50
32   300       4 90.75
33   356       1 91.00
34   304       2 91.25
35   307       3 91.50
36   386       4 91.75
37   331       1 92.00
38   368       2 92.25
39   416       3 92.50
40   374       4 92.75
41   412       1 93.00
42   358       2 93.25
43   416       3 93.50
44   414       4 93.75
45   496       1 94.00
```

my code used to create the model and intervals before plotting

```
#creating the model
model3 = glm(cases ~ date,
         data = aids,
         family = poisson(link='log'))

#now to add approx. 95% confidence envelope around this line
#predict again but at the linear predictor level along with standard errors
my_preds <- predict(model3, newdata=data.frame(aids), se.fit=T, type="link") 

#calculate CI limit since linear predictor is approx. Gaussian
upper <- my_preds$fit+1.96*my_preds$se.fit #this might be logit not log
lower <- my_preds$fit-1.96*my_preds$se.fit

#transform the CI limit to get one at the level of the mean
upper <- exp(upper)/(1+exp(upper)) 
lower <- exp(lower)/(1+exp(lower))

#plotting data
plot(aids$date, aids$cases,
 xlab = 'Date', ylab = 'Cases', pch = 20)

#adding CI lines
plot(aids$date, exp(my_preds$fit), type = "link",
 xlab = 'Date', ylab = 'Cases') #add title
lines(aids$date,exp(my_preds$fit+1.96*my_preds$se.fit),lwd=2,lty=2)
lines(aids$date,exp(my_preds$fit-1.96*my_preds$se.fit),lwd=2,lty=2)
```

outcome i currently get with no data points, the model is correct here but the CI isnt as i have no data points, so the CIs are made incorrectly i think somewhere

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use: `predict(model3, type='response', se.fit=TRUE)`?

Comment: I would be wrong but I thought i needed to use 'link' to work out the CIs here, either way it still leaves me with the same plot with no data and wrong CIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Response to OP's providing full data set.

This started out as a question about plotting data and models on the same graph, but has morphed considerably. You seem you have an answer to the original question. Below is one way to address the rest.

Looking at your (and my) plots it seems clear that poisson glm is just not a good model. To say it differently, the number of cases may vary with date, but is also influenced by other things not in your model (external regressors).

Plotting just your data suggests strongly that you have at least two and perhaps more regimes: time frames where the growth in cases follows different models.

```
ggplot(aids, aes(x=date)) + geom_point(aes(y=cases))
```

[image]

This suggests [segmented regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression). As with most things in R, there is a package for that (more than one actually). The code below uses the `segmented` package to build successive poisson glm using 1 breakpoint (two regimes).

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(segmented)
setDT(aids)        # convert aids to a data.table
aids[, pred:=
       predict(
         segmented(glm(cases~date, .SD, family = poisson), seg.Z = ~date, npsi=1), 
         type='response', se.fit=TRUE)$fit]
ggplot(aids, aes(x=date))+ geom_line(aes(y=pred))+ geom_point(aes(y=cases))
```

[image]

Note that we need to tell `segmented` the count of breakpoints, but not where they are - the algorithm figures that out for you. So here, we see a regime prior to 3Q87 which is well modeled using poission glm, and a regime after that which is not. This is a fancy way of saying that "something happened" around 3Q87 which changed the course of the disease (at least in this data).

The code below does the same thing but for between 1 and 4 breakpoints.

```
get.pred <- \(p.n, p.DT) {
  fit     <- glm(cases~date, p.DT, family=poisson)
  seg.fit <- segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~date, npsi=p.n)
  predict(seg.fit, type='response', se.fit=TRUE)[c('fit', 'se.fit')]
}
gg.dt <- rbindlist(lapply(1:4, \(x) { copy(aids)[, c('pred', 'se'):=get.pred(x, .SD)][, npsi:=x] } ))
ggplot(gg.dt, aes(x=date))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pred-1.96*se, ymax=pred+1.96*se), fill='grey80')+
  geom_line(aes(y=pred))+
  geom_point(aes(y=cases))+
  facet_wrap(~npsi)
```

[image]

Note that the location of the first breakpoint does not seem to change, and also that, notwithstanding the use of the poisson glm the growth appears linear in all but the first regime.

There are goodness-of-fit metrics described in the package documentation which can help you decide how many break points are most consistent with your data.

Finally, there is also the [`mcp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcp/mcp.pdf) package which is a bit more powerful but also a bit more complex to use.

**Original Response**: Here is one way that builds the model predictions and std. error in a `data.table`, then plots using `ggplot`.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
setDT(aids)        # convert aids to a data.table
aids[, c('pred', 'se', 'resid.scale'):=predict(glm(cases~date, data=.SD, family=poisson), type='response', se.fit=TRUE)]
ggplot(aids, aes(x=date))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pred-1.96*se, ymax=pred+1.96*se), fill='grey80')+
  geom_line(aes(y=pred))+
  geom_point(aes(y=cases))
```

[image]

Or, you could let `ggplot` do all the work for you.

```
ggplot(aids, aes(x=date, y=cases))+
  stat_smooth(method = glm, method.args=list(family=poisson))+
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, just tried it although weirdly this code still produces a similar issues (thin CIs like the plot i shower earlier) and i'm not sure how thats possible

Comment: Well, your real dataset goes out to (19)95 so there's much more data. The se~ 1/sqrt(n) so not all that surprising.

Comment: Ok, yeh i see what you mean. I've added an updated plot in the question so you can see what i mean in relation to my data points. It feels wrong so miss that many data points so I think i must have gone wrong somewhere before this

Comment: Can you provide your whole dataset?

Comment: Sure, i've updated the question so now contains the whole df rather than part of it